# CakePHP default Controller without changing URL

Tags: php, cakephp

May be this question is already asked. If it is, please provide the link. I searched but not found what I actually wanted.

I know how to define default controller via `Router::connect()` but that redirects users to a different place. For example, if I do this for domain `www.example.com` :

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'));
```

People coming to `www.example.com` will be redirected to `www.example.com/users/` (see, both URLs aren't same). My question is, what should I do if I want to connect a controller without adding `/:controller` so that users coming to `www.example.com` will be in `www.example.com` but get contents of `UsersController`?

Comment: What about rendering users index view in your home page?

Comment: Didn't get you, would you please clear?

Comment: what controller and action your are getting in `pr($this->params);` output for www.example.com. I will explain my comment more after that

Comment: My router is `Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'))`, this causes `example.com` to redirect `example.com/users/login` (index redirects users to login), so, no output for `example.com`

Comment: `this causes example.com to redirect example.com/users/login (index redirects users to login),` Is your index in accessible to non logged in user as well?

Comment: No. That's created the problem. Now I looked into my `index()` action and get the answer. Thanks for your help :D

Comment: If I could guess your point, You were trying to get the non authorized action in to router connect which was redirecting you to login. You should Auth Allow that action. Because your `Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'));` is correct. Glad to help you..

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your routes.php after

```
Router::connect('/login', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'))
```

Now your `example.com/users/login` should looks like `example.com/login` and address will work.